# Fixed parallax header image

Tags: jquery, css, css-position, parallax

I have been trying to figure out how to achieve an effect similar to this: [ishothim.com](http://ishothim.com/). A fixed div that contains either a header image or slideshow. This div is then overlapped by the rest of the content when the user scrolls down. And a neat button pointing down to scroll to the actual content. I have used css `z-index` to layer the different divs and waypoints.js to make sure the navigation is sticky. But it doesn't seem quite refined and ready yet.

I have a feeling there must be a more elegant jQuery way of doing this, but I don't know where to begin. I have tried parallax scrolling, but it seemed almost too complex for what I want to achieve. There must be something simpler. Any ideas and pointers are very much welcome.

Answer (score 0):

to use `z-index` you must also specify a `position` on the class. in this case, it will most likely be `position: fixed;`